# Typescript Error Property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof Modal'. in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

`i follow ionic 2 tutorials creating weather app I cannot do Model.create(Add) 'create' does not exist on type 'type of Modal' in my app. How ever i follow`http://Ionic2Tutorial.com`tutorials I need to fix this error and this is my 1st ionic app

Comment: you need to provide [mcve]

Comment: please put some code where you are getting error

Comment: `addWeather(){
    let addWeatherModal = Modal.create(Add);
    this.navCtrl.present(`addWeatherModal`);`
  }`